# Exporting specific fields with powershell's export-csv

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to export a list of some user information from Active Directory 2003 using Powershell.

So far, I'm able to display the specific list of properties using something like this:

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PsSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
}

get-qaduser -company "Company","Consultant" `
    -enabled -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties 'givenName','sn','telephoneNumber','mail','company' `
    | sort-object `
    | format-table givenname,sn,company,telephonenumber,mail `
```

However, if I try to pipe the output to export-csv, instead of format-table, I get all the properties of each domain object.

If I do something like the following:

```
    | format-table givenname,sn,company,telephonenumber,mail `
    | export-csv -Delimiter `t -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\scripts\adexport.csv
```

I get a correct number of rows with no data, except some identifier (which makes sense - since the object isn't being passed into export-csv, just a line of text).

How can I export the specific fields to a file?

I am using Quest's ActiveDirectory powershell CMDLETs (http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) to get the data from AD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the `Select-Object` cmdlet in place of `Format-Table`. This should work for you:

```
| select-object givenname,sn,company,telephonenumber,mail `
| export-csv -Delimiter `t -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\scripts\adexport.csv
```